# type '(DatabaseError) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I have no idea why I am getting this error. I got this error after I restarted my app without changing any of the code. It seems related to the `firebase_database` plugin, but I have no idea what is causing this issue in particular.

*I am using Dart 2 preview*

**Error**

```
I/flutter ( 3221): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3221): The following assertion was thrown building MealList:
I/flutter ( 3221): type '(DatabaseError) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr'
I/flutter ( 3221):
I/flutter ( 3221): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 3221): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 3221): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 3221):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new
I/flutter ( 3221):
I/flutter ( 3221): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 3221): #3      new _ControllerSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart)
I/flutter ( 3221): #4      new _BroadcastSubscription (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart)
I/flutter ( 3221): #8      _ListBase&StreamSubscriberMixin^#U0^#U1.listen (package:firebase_database/ui/utils/stream_subscriber_mixin.dart:15:33)
I/flutter ( 3221): #9      new FirebaseList (package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_list.dart:32:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #10     FirebaseAnimatedListState.didChangeDependencies (package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart:153:20)
I/flutter ( 3221): #11     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3739:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #12     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
I/flutter ( 3221): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #17     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #18     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4611:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
I/flutter ( 3221): #25     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #26     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #27     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
I/flutter ( 3221): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #32     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #34     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3916:11)
I/flutter ( 3221): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
I/flutter ( 3221): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #40     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3741:11)
I/flutter ( 3221): #41     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #44     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:729:20)
I/flutter ( 3221): #45     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2205:19)
I/flutter ( 3221): #46     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:722:11)
I/flutter ( 3221): #47     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:254:23)
I/flutter ( 3221): #48     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1666:58)
I/flutter ( 3221): #49     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:740:15)
I/flutter ( 3221): #50     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1666:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #51     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:243:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #52     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:351:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #53     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:169:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #55     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:285:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #56     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1008:12)
I/flutter ( 3221): #57     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:932:20)
I/flutter ( 3221): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #59     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #61     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #63     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #65     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #67     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #69     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #71     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #73     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #75     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:124:11)
I/flutter ( 3221): #76     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:256:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #77     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:194:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #78     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:338:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #80     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #82     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #83     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1138:11)
I/flutter ( 3221): #84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #85     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #86     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #87     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #89     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #91     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #93     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2708:14)
I/flutter ( 3221): #94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #95     __RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin^^#U0^.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #97     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:509:15)
I/flutter ( 3221): #98     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1445:7)
I/flutter ( 3221): #99     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:709:18)
I/flutter ( 3221): #100    _____BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:270:19)
I/flutter ( 3221): #101    ______BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:622:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #102    _____BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #103    ___BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 3221): #104    ___BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 3221): #105    ___BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 3221): #106    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:120:13)
I/flutter ( 3221): #107    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:109:3)
I/flutter ( 3221): (elided 6 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 3221): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3221): Another exception was thrown: type '(DatabaseError) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr'
```

**Code**

```
return new FirebaseAnimatedList(
      //defaultChild: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child("meals/${this.tabSelector}"),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot meals,
          Animation animation, int index) {
        return  new MealCard(
          index: index,
          meals: meals,
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: The package may not be ready for dart 2

Comment: But this error was so sudden, it was working perfectly fine too.